# Can a Web Api controller render a view as a string?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I would like to write a Web Api controller action that would send an email depending on results. I would like to use an MVC View or Partial view with a model of data to render the body of the email.

Is there a way to do this?

I would like something like this:

```
public class NotificationApiController : ApiController
{
    private IMkpContext db;

    public string ViewNotifications()
    {
        var dataModel = GetDataModel();
        if (dataModel != null) 
        {
            SendEmail(dataModel.ToAddress, dataModel.FromAddress, dataModel.Subject, RenderBody("viewName", dataModel);
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Where RenderBody would look up the viewName, populate it with data from dataModel, and render the View as a string.

Comment: I generally use the RazorEngine library to render my views and use that for my emails. It has the added benefit of allowing you to declare your views as strongly typed. http://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/

Comment: I use Postal for the same purpose. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Postal.Mvc5/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don´t want to go with the RazorEngine approach suggested in the comments, you could define a class like this:

```
public static class ViewUtil
{
    public static string RenderPartial(string partialName, object model)
    {
        var sw = new StringWriter();
        var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);

        // point to an empty controller
        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "EmptyController");

        var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(new RequestContext(httpContext, routeData), new EmptyController());

        var view = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerContext, partialName).View;

        view.Render(new ViewContext(controllerContext, view, new ViewDataDictionary { Model = model }, new TempDataDictionary(), sw), sw);

        return sw.ToString();
    }
}

class EmptyController : Controller { }
```

Comment: I got an exception: error CS0103: The name 'model' does not exist in the current context. I guess I need something else to pass the model to the view....