# How to send raw html with JS-data in WebAPI2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I know that in ASP.NET MVC we can send raw HTML-page by using Html.Raw().

Now I have an WebAPI2 application with HttpGet method : user sends some values X and Y :

```
public string\ActionResult DrawMap(double x, double y)
```

Also in project I have some HTML page where some JS draw map with this **x** and **y**. 
I want this method take this HTML file, draw map, prepare updated HTML file and return it as a seqeunce of string. 
Should I use Html.Raw(), what means I need to use MVC library. Or there are another more appropriate and more correct approaches to implement it?

Then this string will be displayed by Swift\Android, something like this sample:

```
var attrStr = NSAttributedString(
        data: "MY_HTML".dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true),
        options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
        documentAttributes: nil,
        error: nil)
label.attributedText = attrStr
```

Comment: So do you need your web api to render a mvc view?

Comment: @peco, this service based on restful get\post of json\xml in general, but one more functionality we want to achieve - return the pure html string that could be proceeded by Android\iOS

Comment: Should I separate this functionalities into 2 projects : MVC and WebAPI?

Comment: If you want web api to render a mvc view you could check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36161381/can-a-web-api-controller-render-a-view-as-a-string/36178420#36178420